# Pandas date_range with only hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: python, pandas

I want a list of timestamps ranging from `00:00:00` to `23:45:00` using `pandas` `date_range`.

I tried like this

```
pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('00:00:00'), end=pd.Timestamp('23:45:00'), freq='15T')
```

Even though I haven't provided the Year, Month and Date, the output I got is like this

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-14 00:00:00', '2018-09-14 00:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 00:30:00', '2018-09-14 00:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 01:00:00', '2018-09-14 01:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 01:30:00', '2018-09-14 01:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 02:00:00', '2018-09-14 02:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 02:30:00', '2018-09-14 02:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 03:00:00', '2018-09-14 03:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 03:30:00', '2018-09-14 03:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 04:00:00', '2018-09-14 04:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 04:30:00', '2018-09-14 04:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 05:00:00', '2018-09-14 05:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 05:30:00', '2018-09-14 05:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 06:00:00', '2018-09-14 06:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 06:30:00', '2018-09-14 06:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 07:00:00', '2018-09-14 07:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 07:30:00', '2018-09-14 07:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 08:00:00', '2018-09-14 08:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 08:30:00', '2018-09-14 08:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 09:00:00', '2018-09-14 09:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 09:30:00', '2018-09-14 09:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 10:00:00', '2018-09-14 10:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 10:30:00', '2018-09-14 10:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 11:00:00', '2018-09-14 11:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 11:30:00', '2018-09-14 11:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 12:00:00', '2018-09-14 12:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 12:30:00', '2018-09-14 12:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 13:00:00', '2018-09-14 13:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 13:30:00', '2018-09-14 13:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 14:00:00', '2018-09-14 14:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 14:30:00', '2018-09-14 14:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 15:00:00', '2018-09-14 15:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 15:30:00', '2018-09-14 15:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 16:00:00', '2018-09-14 16:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 16:30:00', '2018-09-14 16:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 17:00:00', '2018-09-14 17:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 17:30:00', '2018-09-14 17:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 18:00:00', '2018-09-14 18:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 18:30:00', '2018-09-14 18:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 19:00:00', '2018-09-14 19:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 19:30:00', '2018-09-14 19:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 20:00:00', '2018-09-14 20:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 20:30:00', '2018-09-14 20:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 21:00:00', '2018-09-14 21:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 21:30:00', '2018-09-14 21:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 22:00:00', '2018-09-14 22:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 22:30:00', '2018-09-14 22:45:00',
               '2018-09-14 23:00:00', '2018-09-14 23:15:00',
               '2018-09-14 23:30:00', '2018-09-14 23:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='15T')
```

I know I can strip the needed Hour, Minute and Second value from this. But I am wondering is there are direct way for this.

Can this be done in pandas.?

Comment: `pd.date_range(...).time` gives you only the time components.

Comment: @Graipher, yes it will give time component. I want something like `00:00:00` , `00:15:00` ........ `23:45:00`

Comment: wrap a `list(map(str, ...))` around it to get the strings?

Comment: I was looking for some direct way using pandas only.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can extract your required form of time from timestamp with 'strftime' Function

```
pd.date_range("11:00", "21:30", freq="30min").strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Out:

```
array(['11:00:00', '11:30:00', '12:00:00', '12:30:00', '13:00:00',
       '13:30:00', '14:00:00', '14:30:00', '15:00:00', '15:30:00',
       '16:00:00', '16:30:00', '17:00:00', '17:30:00', '18:00:00',
       '18:30:00', '19:00:00', '19:30:00', '20:00:00', '20:30:00',
       '21:00:00', '21:30:00'], dtype='<U8')
```

Comment: Nice one. I was looking for something like a pd.time_range. Stripping is okay for my application but I was looking for other options.

Answer (score 6):

Since `pandas.date_range` gives you, well a range of dates, and there is no `pandas.time_range`, I think you are left with not many options.

The easiest way is to just take the time components from the dates:

```
>>> r = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('00:00:00'), end=pd.Timestamp('23:45:00'), freq='15T')
>>> r.time
array([datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 15), datetime.time(0, 30),
       ...
       datetime.time(23, 15), datetime.time(23, 30), datetime.time(23, 45)], dtype=object)
```

This returns a numpy array of `datetime.time` objects. You can then do with that whatever you want. If you just want their string representations, the easiest way is probably to use the built-in `map`:

```
>>> list(map(str, pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('00:00:00'), end=pd.Timestamp('23:45:00'), freq='15T').time))
['00:00:00',
 '00:15:00',
 ...
 '23:45:00']
```

Comment: I think I have to settle with stripping using strftime

Comment: @SreeramTP: I agree, that seems like the most succinct approach. in that case, you probably wanted to accept that answer, instead of mine?

Comment: It would have been really convenient if there is something like `pd.Timestamp('00:00:00')`. I have a dataframe with a column in this hour, mint, sec format. I wanted to do timestamp comaprioson rather than string comparions.

Comment: @SreeramTP: You do get the time objects with the method I showed above. With that you can do comparisons between the time objects, instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension? I don't know if this is direct as you want

```
[date.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for date in pd.date_range(... )]
```